# Make a loop pause until a user inputs something, then continue, in Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I am creating a HTML5 app and here is what I want to do:

I want to create a loop which for which as long as x is smaller than y, it will pause, ask a user for input, and once the user inputs something, it will check if x is smaller than y, pause and ask the user for input....until x is no longer smaller than y.

I want the input to be buttons from the Framework7 action sheet: http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/action-sheet.html#.VFhLMBb4oUM
So I want the loop to wait until the user presses one of those buttons.

Is this possible to do in Jquery or Javascript?

----Edit-----

Sorry I missed a very important detail. The program runs, a user inputs words (we'll call this w), once he/she does that and clicks a button. After this, the input is seperated into an array where each word is a different value (call this array words).
I have an array which stores the words and also what parts of speech they are. The user will determine what part of speech they are.

I want a loop or event (both) to fire which something like this:

```
for(i=0;i<words.length){
var buttons = [
    {
        text: 'What is "'+listandtypes[0][i]+'"', //word
        label: true
    },
    {
        text: 'Adjective',
        onClick: function () {
            listandtypes[1][i] = "adj"; //part of speech
            myApp.alert('Button1 clicked');
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Adverb',
        onClick: function () {
            listandtypes[1][i] = "adv";
            myApp.alert('Button2 clicked');
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Noun',
        onClick: function () {
            listandtypes[1][i] = "noun";
            myApp.alert('Button2 clicked');
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Verb',
        onClick: function () {
            listandtypes[1][i] = "verb";
            myApp.alert('Button2 clicked');
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Other',
        color: 'red',
        onClick: function () {
            listandtypes[1][i] = "idk";
            myApp.alert('Cancel clicked');
        }
    },
];
myApp.actions(buttons);
        } //I want this loop to wait until a button is pressed
//More code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of feature is better handled with events instead of a loop. 
Create an event on input. Either a button click, enter press or tabbing off the field. Attach an event handler and check the condition there.